# SortableJS: Item changes position after put request

Tags: javascript, mongoose, sortablejs

i am building a web page and as database i use mongodb (mongoose). I have one page where i list some documents (id, date, status etc..). Then i am able to click on the item to see more detailed information. On that page i have added a dropdown menu to change some values. When i change a value (ajax put request -> mongoose findByIdAndUpdate) and then go back to the list page, the order of my list has changed. The item i have changed is then the first item in the list.

My for loop to create the list:

```
<div id="simpleList" class="list-group">
    <% items.forEach(function(item) { %>
    <div class="box-item list-group-item">

        <div class="box-normal row-1 margin-left filtered">
            <p><%= item.itemId %></p>
        </div>

        <div class="box-normal row-1 margin-left filtered">
            <p><%= item.projectName %></p>
        </div>

        <a id="link-text" class="bold row-1 align-right" href="srequest/<%= item.itemId %>">More details</a>
        <p class="row-1 icon-drag">
            <span class="my-handle"><i class="fas fa-arrows-alt-v fa-3x" title="Move item"></i></span>
        </p>

    </div>
    <% }); %>
</div>
```

The code for the SortableJS list:

```
<script>
Sortable.create(simpleList, { 
    store: {
  filter: '.filtered', // 'filtered' class is not draggable
  handle: '.my-handle',
  animation: 0,

        /**
         * Get the order of elements. Called once during initialization.
         * @param   {Sortable}  sortable
         * @returns {Array}
         */
        get: function (sortable) {
            var order = localStorage.getItem(sortable.options.group.name);

            return order ? order.split('|') : [];
        },
        /**
         * Save the order of elements. Called onEnd (when the item is dropped).
         * @param {Sortable}  sortable
         */
        set: function (sortable) {
            var order = sortable.toArray();

            localStorage.setItem(sortable.options.group.name, order.join('|'));
        }
  }
 });

</script>
```

Even if i disable the sortable function with the option "disable: true" the item will still become the first when i update something.

I guess the updated item will be treated as a new item and therefore moves on top of the list. Is there a way to store the order of the list before i leave that page?

Thanks in advance for your help!

BR
Christian

Comment: Try setting the group option to have a group name. Ex. `group: 'stored'`

Comment: Hey Owen, thanks for your answer but unfortunately this didnt help.

Answer (score 0):

You need a group name and store's function need only get and set parameters. This will work correctly.

```
Sortable.create(simpleList, { 
  group: "myList",
  filter: '.filtered', // 'filtered' class is not draggable
  handle: '.my-handle',
  animation: 0,
  store: {
        /**
         * Get the order of elements. Called once during initialization.
         * @param   {Sortable}  sortable
         * @returns {Array}
         */
        get: function (sortable) {
            var order = localStorage.getItem(sortable.options.group.name);

            return order ? order.split('|') : [];
        },
        /**
         * Save the order of elements. Called onEnd (when the item is dropped).
         * @param {Sortable}  sortable
         */
        set: function (sortable) {
            var order = sortable.toArray();

            localStorage.setItem(sortable.options.group.name, order.join('|'));
        }
  }
 });
```